# Calculated Formula for Finding three diferent results

Tags: calculated-column-formula, if-condition

I am working on a calculated formula based on my `[Tracking Number]` column to get the following results:

1. Find "Andrews"  return the result "ANDREWS".
2. Find "Bolling"  return the result "BOLLING".
3. Find "Pentagon" return the result "PENTAGON".

The formula that I have come up with returns "ANDREWS" when it finds "Andrews", and returns #VALUE! for all the others.

This is the formula that I am using.  Please help me resolve this issue.

```
=IF(FIND("Andrews",[Tracking Number]),"ANDREWS",IF(FIND("Bolling",[Tracking Number]),"BOLLING",IF(FIND("Pentagon",[Tracking Number]),"PENTAGON")))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mike, Both of your solutions resolved the issue.   Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIND function is not real friendly… if there is not a match it returns an error. Here's one solution:

```
=IF( NOT(ISERR(FIND("Andrews",[Tracking Number]))), "ANDREWS",
      IF( NOT(ISERR(FIND("Bolling",[Tracking Number]))), "BOLLING",
         IF( NOT(ISERR(FIND("Pentagon",[Tracking Number]))), "PENTAGON", "none" )))
```

Here's an alternate solution:

```
=IF( ISNUMBER(FIND("Andrews",[Tracking Number])), "ANDREWS",
      IF( ISNUMBER(FIND("Bolling",[Tracking Number])), "BOLLING",
         IF( ISNUMBER(FIND("Pentagon",[Tracking Number])), "PENTAGON", "none" )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You are missing last ELSE part in third third IF statement

```
=IF(
    FIND("Andrews",[Tracking Number]),
    "ANDREWS",
    IF(
        FIND("Bolling",[Tracking Number]),
        "BOLLING",
        IF(
            FIND("Pentagon",[Tracking Number]),
            "PENTAGON",
            " !!! NEED VALUE HERE !! "
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I tried adding the last ELSE part as you suggested and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but great that other solution by Mike Smith worked!